# I want to filter column on specific names in column, and delete these

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have values in my dataframe column that are bad for my data and I need to remove them, I only know how to do this with one row:

```
df=df[df.name!='susan']
```

but I want to delete 4 other names within my column

Comment: df=df[~df['name'].isin(['susan','billy','jimbob','steven'])

Comment: `df=df[~df.name.isin(['susan', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'])]` need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html).